# JavaScript at the end of document...function is not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**This is very embarrassing.** I have looked through several similar posts here on stackoverflow, something along the lines of Reference Error: Function xxx is not defined. No luck. Of course, I have indeed Google'd this as well, but I have only come up with dead ends.

**Long story short:** I have inherited a long PHP page. Minified and concatenated scripts and stylesheets all over the place. Business logic injected by way of backbone.js. The people who wrote all that stuff are off limits for me. I KNOW, that's bad, but I cannot change the politics of this situation.

**Here's the deal:** I need to add twitter bootstrap tooltips to a bunch of icon-buttons on a dynamically inserted page overlay. This page overlay comes and goes and is not always part of the DOM. So the twitter bootstrap tooltip initiation does not affect that page overlay -- simply because it doesn't exist until someone clicks a button.

I was able to add an "onclick" to that button that calls the page overlay, calling a function that a) checks for the existence of the page overlay and b) initiates the tooltips on the page overlay. That function is called ittps(). Here it is, at the very bottom of that one PHP page:

```
<!-- START MANAGEMENT PAGES -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //  INSTANTIATE TOOLTIPS ON MANAGEMENT PAGES
    //  THIS FUNCTION GETS CALLED FROM: instances-grid-parent
        function ittps(w){

        if(w=='backup'){

            if( $(".management").length ){
                if( $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").length ){
                    $(".mngmnt-icon-restore, [data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
                    console.log('And.......................we are good.');
                }else{
                    setTimeout("ittps();", 500);
                }
            }else{
                console.log('Nothing to do here.......................');
                setTimeout("ittps();", 500);
            }

        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Perhaps I'm too naive, thinking that the function inside the script tag at the very bottom will be available to the rest of the document?

Basically, when the button gets clicked, I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: ittps(w) is not defined.
```

So after trying to add `window.ittps = function(w){` to the code and doing a bunch of other things (such as trying to add the function to the `$(document).ready(function(){` queue, nothing has worked. I am ready to throw this thing at a hard cubicle wall here in another hour.

Does anyone have any ideas as how to make this work? I can get it to work, if I wait for the page overlay to show up and then run the function inside the JavaScript console (Firebug).

PS: I cannot add any JavaScript to the contents of the page overlay, since those contents get rendered by backbone.js. I don't know if there would be a work-around for that. At this point, I'll take any advice and run with it. Thanks.

Final Note: The code itself runs perfectly, if I execute it inside the JavaScript console (Firebug). Once I run it, the tootlips show up as desired:

```
var w = 'backup';
if(w=='backup'){

    if( $(".management").length ){
        if( $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").length ){
            $(".mngmnt-icon-restore, [data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
            console.log('And.......................we are good.');
        }else{
            setTimeout("ittps('backup');", 500);
        }
    }else{
        console.log('Nothing to do here.......................');
        setTimeout("ittps('backup');", 500);
    }
}
```

And even though executing this code in the JavaScript console works, when the page overlay is present, as requested here is the HTML with the tooltip code.

```
                <div class="slct-with-icns">
                    <span class="mngmnt-icons mngmnt-icon-restore" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Restore" data-original-title="Restore">.</span>
                    <span class="mngmnt-icons mngmnt-icon-download" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Download" data-original-title="Download">.</span>
                    <span class="mngmnt-icons mngmnt-icon-schedule" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Schedule a Backup" data-original-title="Schedule a Backup">.</span>
                    <span class="mngmnt-icons mngmnt-icon-test" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Test the selected restore action" data-original-title="Test the selected restore action">.</span>
                    <span class="mngmnt-icons mngmnt-icon-delete" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete the selected backup" data-original-title="Delete the selected backup">.</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML? The part where you're adding the onclick.

Comment: Show us how you bound the function call to that button.

Comment: You should't pass strings to `setTimeout`, but functions.

Comment: There is a closing bracket `}` missing in the function definition. Maybe that is a problem? Are there any javascript errors while loading the page?

Comment: @petrch - Duh! I AM SOOOOOOOO EMBARRASSED! I cannot believe I missed that. Please post your comment as an answer and I will give you points.

Comment: @petrch: Only if the code was invoked from a different script, which is apparently now the case. I wonder why OP told us about the ReferenceError and not the SyntaxError.

Comment: Ace - thanks :)
@amnotiam - well, the SyntaxError should be reported in the Firebug too, while loading the page.

Comment: @petrch: Yeah, that's my point. I would think that would have been the first thing OP would have seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a closing bracket `}` missing in the function definition. So the `<script> ... </script>` block has a syntax error in it, is not evaluated and the `function ittps(w)` is not defined.